# resetting bootstrap-contextmenu after jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap [bootstrap-contextmenu](https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu) on my page. I do a jquery `.load(...)` to reload the menu where the context menu is located. Then I re initialize the context menu in JS. I think I need to reset or delete the old context menu first because there is some error with the context menu after I call `.load(...)` and try to call the context menu initialization code again. I think it might be overwritting the old menu and creating problems! How do I reset the context menu on the elements I've just dynamically added to my page?

```
$('.context').contextmenu({
  target:'#context-menu', 
  before: function(e,context) {
    // execute code before context menu if shown
  },
  onItem: function(context,e) {
    // execute on menu item selection
  }
})
```

Comment: I've definitely seen this kind of behavior before. Reloading menus, dialogs etc via load can cause issues. I think it is related to the fact that these elements add a lot of other elements to the page, then when you load the new content and call "contextmenu" again, it adds the elements again causing issues. I have seen specific libraries that offer functionality to allow you to "destroy" an existing menu etc. e.g. http://lab.jakiestfu.com/contextjs/

Comment: that may be true, but if I can just figure out how to kill the code that initialized the first context menu, I should be golden! I think...

Comment: I used to pass back a unique id for the loaded menu and "get around" the problem that way. I don't have access to the code anymore, but in pseudo code load the new contents and .then navigate down the load target children to the new menu, lift the ID out of the data and call dialog using that. Hope this helps.